# Weight doesn't limit width of layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a list of items I would like to show. I have written the following code
for each item's view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingEnd="12dp"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"    
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="6"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="4">
            <TextView
                android:id="+@id/receipt_item_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="item name" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/receipt_item_name"
                android:text="selected by 2 others"
                android:textSize="10sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:text="10$" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But when the text in receipt_item_name is too long it makes the next
textview shift right. How can I make sure each view's weight is solid?
or What else can I do to get the same effect?

[image: looks terrible..]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `width` of every layout that has the `weight` to 0 like this:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="4">
```

And for these two as well:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:text="10$" />
```

The thing is, when you set both the `weight` and the `width`, the `width` takes precedence and ignores the `weight` attribute.